# pygme spritecollideany Argument must be rect style object

Tags: python, pygame

```py
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  
        self.image = None  
        self.master_image = None      
        self.rect = (0,0)            
        self.old_frame = -1         
        self.frame = 0            
        self.frame_width = 1        
        self.frame_height = 1        
        self.first_frame = 0         
        self.last_frame = 0           
        self.columns = 1              
        self.last_time = 0           
        self.direction = 0           
        self.x = 100                  
        self.y = 100                  
        self.speed = 1.5

    def load(self, filename, width, height, columns):
        self.master_image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha() 
        self.frame_width = width            
        self.frame_height = height        
        self.rect = Rect(self.x,self.y, width, height)    
        self.columns = columns            


  
        rect = self.master_image.get_rect()       
        self.last_frame = (rect.width // width) * (rect.height // height)  - 1 
     


    def update(self, current_time, fps=60):
        if current_time > self.last_time + fps:  
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > self.last_frame:     
                self.frame = self.first_frame
            self.last_time = current_time          

        if self.frame != self.old_frame:     
            frame_x = (self.frame % self.columns) * self.frame_width       
            frame_y = (self.frame // self.columns) * self.frame_height     
            rect = Rect(frame_x, frame_y, self.frame_width, self.frame_height)
            self.image = self.master_image.subsurface(rect)    
            self.old_frame = self.frame
```

```py
attacker = None
attacker = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player,food)
if attacker != None:
    if pygame.sprite.collide_circle_ratio(0.65)(player,attacker):
        score +=2
        food.remove(attacker)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem the initialization of the `rect` attribute. The `rect` attribute must be a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.htmlv) object:

<s>`self.rect = (0,0)`</s>

```py
self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 0, 0)
```